# How do I associate numbers with my array list?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner, calculator

I have created two spinners, a meal type spinner (e.g. Breakfast, lunch...) and a food spinner (e.g. porridge). Once the user has selected their meal type the associated foods appear in the second spinner.

Now I want to be able to create a food calculator which will multiply a set of calories for each food with a number entered by the user but I'm not sure how I associate my numbers with my array list for my spinner. Is it something like this?

```
private void chooseBreakfast() {
    planspinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist.add("Porridge-40g/140cal");
    planlist.add("Coffee-10g/10cal");
    planlist.add("Toast-30g/87cal");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);

    planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    planspinner1.setAdapter(planAdapter1);

    ArrayList<int> food = newArrayList<int>();
    food.add(4);
    food.add(1);
    food.add(3);

}
```

Comment: How about implementing a custom object to hold the data for you, thus you only need to create one array?

Comment: why you didn't use a HashMap and each element contains the food and it's corresponding amount of calories ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a list objects using a food class like

```
{
  private string name;
  private int id;
  private double calories
}
```

and use that in your spinner

Comment: that's a solution if he has only 1 item, but he has array of items

Comment: can he do objects list ?

Comment: yea he may create an array of objects(like class, Map, ...etc) each object contains the food and it's corresponding amount of calories

Comment: he can use a loop for add that objects